# Using a if-statement in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Im trying to get my programm to print numbers in given symbols

```
arv=input("Sisesta arv: ")
suurus=int(input("Sisesta suurus "))


arvulist=list(x.strip() for x in arv)


def rida_V(number):
    sektsioon=[]
    n=0
    kokku= ""
    for i in range(len(arv)):

        if number[i] in {"0","8","9","4"}:
            sektsioon.append("|" + " "*suurus + "|" + " "*suurus)
        elif number[i] in {"1","2","3","7"}:
            sektsioon.append(" " + " "*suurus + "|" + " "*suurus)
        elif number[i] in {"5","6"}:
            sektsioon.append("|" + " "*suurus + " " + " "*suurus)


    return sektsioon


for i in range(suurus):
    print("".join(rida_V(arvulist)))
```

it prints

```
Sisesta arv: 1234
Sisesta suurus 4
     |         |         |         |    
     |         |         |         |    
     |         |         |         |    
     |         |         |         |
```

but i expect it to print out

```
Sisesta arv: 1234
Sisesta suurus 4
     |         |         |    |    |    
     |         |         |    |    |    
     |         |         |    |    |    
     |         |         |    |    |
```

why doesnt it go through the if statements again when its doing another loop
i cant get my head around it.
how can i fix this?

Comment: It prints exactly what you're expecting, there is nothing to fix. Maybe you're running the wrong code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a minor suggestion, use list comprehensions instead of `list()`.
This runs correctly from my command line:

```
arv=input("Sisesta arv: ")
suurus=int(input("Sisesta suurus "))
arvulist= [x.strip() for x in arv]
def rida_V(number):
    sektsioon=[]
    n=0
    kokku= ""
    for i in range(len(arv)):

        if number[i] in {"0","8","9","4"}:
            sektsioon.append("|" + " "*suurus + "|" + " "*suurus)
        elif number[i] in {"1","2","3","7"}:
            sektsioon.append(" " + " "*suurus + "|" + " "*suurus)
        elif number[i] in {"5","6"}:
            sektsioon.append("|" + " "*suurus + " " + " "*suurus)
    return sektsioon

for i in range(suurus):
    print("".join(rida_V(arvulist)))
```

Output:

```
Sisesta arv: 1234
Sisesta suurus 4
     |         |         |    |    |
     |         |         |    |    |
     |         |         |    |    |
     |         |         |    |    |
```

Comment: Glad to help. If I'm not mistaken, it's the optimal python-esque way to do it